# Java cannot find symbol - Methods not able to be accessed from a different class. Possible Java Generics or Inheritance misunderstanding

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types, parameters

So I am building onto (finishing) a program for homework that gives me a class that uses type parameters to build a linked-list data structure. The class has an inner-class that builds the nodes. Here is a simplified version of it...

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
    private static class Node<T> {
        public T data;
        //node next,prev variables + constructor
    }
    //methods to add, get, remove, etc nodes on the list  
}
```

This class does great. No problems with it. Now I also have a gameBoard class...

```
public class gameBoard{
     LinkedList gameBoard;

     public gameBoard(){
         //create new board
         gameBoard = new LinkedList();
     }

     public void addPiece(int name){
         gamePiece newPiece = new gamePiece(name);
         gameBoard.add(newPiece);
     }
}
```

And a gamePiece class...

```
public class gamePiece{
    int gamePieceName;
    public gamePiece(int name){
       gamePieceName = name;
    }

    //view game piece name
    public int viewPieceName(){
        return gamePieceName;
    }
}
```

So the gameBoard has gamePieces, which are stored in a linked-list data structure. I am storing each individual gamePiece in a node, and each node is connected to the other pieces (next and previous), forming the board. I can insert gamePieces into the board (into the an instance of the LinkedList class and into a node), but when I access that node and the gamePiece within, I cannot call methods associated with the gamePiece (from the gamePiece class).

When directly interacting with the gamePiece class via JGrasp, however, I can create a new instance of a gamePiece and play with its methods just fine. However, if I throw this piece into a node in a linked list, I want to be able to access the methods for the gamePiece still.

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
return gameBoard.linkedList.getFirstNode().viewPieceName();
                                          ^
symbol:   method viewPieceName()
location: class Object
```

To clarify that error message, getFirstNode() is a method within the LinkedList class that gets the first node in the list (and returns the gamePiece object, not the whole node), and viewPieceName() is found within the gamePiece class. I can call viewPieceName() just fine by using JGrasp's interaction feature where I directly create a gamePiece object and mess with its methods. However, I cannot seem to access the methods through the LinkedList.

Comment: You should include the code of the relevant classes/methods. Otherwise, it's hard to help you.

Comment: @Eran Added more code of the relevant classes/methods. Thank you.

Comment: Please show us the declaration of the linked list reference variable and the assignment into it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I added code into the gameBoard class (where a new LinkedList is declared, etc.)

Comment: Are you sure that code compiles? Your LinkedList variable is named board, but you are assigning to a variable named gameBoard which is also the name of the class.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Fixed. Copied it down wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your declaration should be:

```
LinkedList<gamePiece> gameBoard;
```

And further down

```
gameBoard = new LinkedLiest<gamePiece>;
```

This is the way you tell a generic type what its actual base type is.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is confusing due to you have two different generics with the same name T.

Use either non-static inner class:

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
    private class Node { // <== Either non-static
        public T data;   //     and direct T usage
        //node next,prev variables + constructor
    }
    //methods to add, get, remove, etc nodes on the list  
}
```

or different generic names:

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
    private static class Node<E> { // <== or different generic name
        public E data;
        //node next,prev variables + constructor
    }
    //methods to add, get, remove, etc nodes on the list  
}
```